# How to align text vertically in a text box using google app script for slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am working on a project that requires text to be aligned vertically in a text box on a google slide.  I have the following function that aligns the text horizontally to the left (START) position of the box.  How can i set the box to also align vertically to the center?

```
function insertHazardTxt (mySlide, txtStats, txtWording) {
  var shape = mySlide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, txtStats.left, txtStats.top, txtStats.width, txtStats.height);
  var textRange=shape.getText();
  var paragraphs=textRange.getParagraphs();
  var insertedText = textRange.appendText(txtWording);
  insertedText.getTextStyle()
    .setFontFamily("Libre Franklin")
    .setFontSize(txtStats.size)
    .setBold(true) 
  . setForegroundColor(255,255,255)
  paragraphs[0].getRange().getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.START);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set the vertical alignment of the internal text in a shape on Google Slides using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about using `setContentAlignment`? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var textRange=shape.getText();
```

#### To:

```
var textRange = shape.setContentAlignment(SlidesApp.ContentAlignment.MIDDLE).getText();
```

- In this modification, the vertical alignment of the internal text in the shape is the center. In the current stage, there are `TOP`, `MIDDLE`, and `BOTTOM`.

#### References:

- [setContentAlignment(contentAlignment)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#setcontentalignmentcontentalignment)
- [Enum ContentAlignment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/content-alignment)

Comment: @Brian Planz Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.